# Get Color From CSS in Typescript in Angular2 App

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Angular2 and Angular Material to do theming.  In my theme scss, I have:

```
$primary: mat-palette($mat-teal-custom, 500, 400, 900);
$accent:  mat-palette($mat-grey4, 500, 200, 600);
```

and I have an alternate theme later on.  In one of my components, I have a bar chart, and I'm set the colors of the bars.  I have some logic that sets the colors in various ways, but I want to have a default color as a function of the current theme and get back to it if the user wants to.  So, I need to know what the color was.  I can't figure out how to do that.

My hack is to have something in my bar-chart.component.scss that looks like:

```
.trythis { 
    color: mat-color($primary);
}
```

and an empty div in my html:

```
<div class="trythis"></div>
```

and then in my .ts I can do:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("trythis");
var style = window.getComputedStyle(elems[0],null).getPropertyValue("color");
```

but that is really ugly.

What is the right Typescripty / Angularly way to get that color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, unless you apply the css via `ngStyle` or `[style]` there is no angular way of fetching the the css value of an element from the class file.

Edit: another way to fetch a css prop is get the element and then `myDiv.style.backgroundColor` for example or`window.getComputedStyle(elementRef.nativeElement)`